# ffmpeg - Add moving text periodically to top of video

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I add moving text to my videos through ffmpeg but only at the top of the screen. I would like to add a moving text banner that moves across the screen every **180 seconds** and takes **10 seconds** to completely move across the screen (right to left)

The text should say `Get more information at xyz.com`

I would also like to specify the text colour and size.

Answer (score 0):

You would need the drawtext filter, something like this:

```
drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font.ttf':fontcolor=0xRRGGBB:fontsize=20:x='W-(W+tw)*mod(t\,10)/10':y='H/20':enable='lt(mod(t\,180)\,10)':text='Get more information at xyz.com'
```